# tab delimited file too big for for loop and readlines? Or is it something simpler?

Tags: python, file-handling, csv

I have a tab delimited file that I have to extract info from as a command line argument. I do so as follows:

```
      import re
      import sys
      dataA=[]
      dataB=[]
      BIOGRID=sys.argv
      with open("interactors.txt", "w") as interactors:
          for data in BIOGRID:
             for smalldata in data:
                smalldata=re.split(r'\t', smalldata)
                   if smalldata[14] == "SCC2":
                      smalldata[1].append(dataA)#append to a list and write this to a file
                elif smalldata[15] == "SCC2":
                      smalldata[1].append(dataB)
          interactors.write(dataA)
          interactors.write(dataB)
```

However when I type the command into my terminal: python "script_name" "argument": 
I get the following error:

```
   File "jpinneyQ1.py", line 9, in <module>
     if smalldata[14] == "SCC2":
 IndexError: list index out of range
```

Does this mean that the file is simply too big for the way that I am searching it?

I opted to use a for loop instead of readlines because I thought it would be too big but if it's still too big then is there any other way that I can search it and extract data?

Or could it just be the fact that the command thinks that the file doesn't have 15 columns and hence it is out of bounds.... however I am not familiar at all with tab delimited files but I'm pretty sure that the file has 17 columns...

Comment: No, you have lines that just don't have 15 separate elements after splitting on tabs. You should really use the `csv` module rather than manually split with a regular expression (and why not just use `smalldata.split('\t')`, as a matter of interest?)

Comment: Also, `smalldata[1]` is a string, not a file object. You cannot call `.write()` on a string.

Comment: You can use pandas. `df = pd.read_csv('filename',sep = '\t')`.
this will read your tab limited file data.

Comment: @RohanAmrute: but pandas comes with a lot of dependencies. `csv.reader(fileobj, delimiter='\t')` also reads a tab-delimited file.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have used pandas to read tsv files.its efficient enough.

Comment: @RohanAmrute Martin didn't say anything about efficiency, he was talking about *dependencies*, and pandas does have a lot of them--making the choice to use the csv module better, IMHO, especially if you don't need pandas processing power for your task.

Comment: @RohanAmrute: sure, but not everyone needs the whole package. I didn't say it wouldn't work, I said that installing Pandas and learning how to use it can be a significant investment too.

Comment: Ok. i take my words back. but its good to learn pandas. did not mean to offend anyone :)

Comment: so in answer to Martijn's original question: I am inexperienced and find csv files cumbersome- I have since taken your advice and modified the script such that I append the "smalldata[1]" strings to a list and then write the list to a file (see edits above) but it still returns the same error??

Comment: What are you passing as `"argument"` in your command line - the whole contents of this tab-separated file, or just its filename? If you're passing the filename surely your code needs to get that filename from `sys.argv[1]` and open that file, then use `readline` to read data from it? Otherwise `smalldata[14]` is going to give an error because `sys.argv[0]` wasn't a list with fifteen elements.

Comment: ...or, better, `for line in myfile`